# DrawerLayout with WebView as Menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library

I have a DrawerLayout with two WebViews. One should act as a menu for the other. Both webpages load as expected, also I can drag the Menu-Webview from the left and click it.

Unfortunately clicking it only closes the drawer instead of doing anything witht he WebView.

Is this somehow doable?

To clarify: there is nothing else in the Layout file. Ill post the XML here if I get the chance.

Comment: Could you please post XML?